R stm package plot custom labels font size
In page 19 of the stm tutorial, Figure 6: Graphical display of topical prevalence contrast
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/vignettes/stmVignette.pdf
How to change the font size of the custom lables of Figure 6 (i.e., font size of 'Obama', 'Sarah Palin', 'Bush Presidency' become smaller / bigger)?
I've tried to add text.cex to the code, but has no results.

Perhaps there's an issue using the 'correct' plotting function; maybe try using plot.STM() with text.cex = 2, instead of plot(), and see if there's a difference?

Since I want to plot a graphical display of topical prevalence contrast, so I think using plot.STM() might not be appropriate

Right! Yep; the class of prep is "estimateEffect", so the plotting function used 'internally' when you type plot() is plot.estimateEffect() (https://github.com/bstewart/stm/blob/dbabf3405c660452bffc8bd1aaf72f7ea3867319/R/plot.estimateEffect.R#L4). Unfortunately this plotting function doesn't appear to have a 'cex' parameter, or any other way of resizing the text. One option would be to run par(cex = 1.2) before you run your plot (all of the text is larger), or you could exclude the custom.labels and place the labels on the plot yourself. Sorry this wasn't the answer you were hoping for

Actually, try par(cex.axis = 1.4) before plotting and see you get your desired outcome @James

running par(cex = 1.2) before running the plot works for me. Thanks @jared_mamrot. I got another question. I wonder if I can decide the side of the text to be appeared. For example, for 'Obama' and 'Sarah Palin' I would like to put it on the left hand side of the dot while for 'Bush Presidency' I would like to put it on the right hand side of the dot. Is this possible?

Glad you solved the issue @James. I can't figure out a way to plot the text on the other side sorry; perhaps try posting another question and see if anyone else has any ideas?

@jared_mamrot, for plotting the text on the other side, please refer to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78701007/r-stm-package-plot-decide-side-of-the-text)
